# Check the json comparison without index hardcoding?

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I have a JSON with a particular key repeated under many indexes of JSON. I should check all index if the keys values match my values. How can I achieve in it robotframework or python?

JSON:

```
 ${Getjson}=    [ { "ID": "100", "name": "john" }, { "ID": "101", "name": "jack" }, { "ID": "102", "name": "jim" } ]
```

These JSON changes its name every time its index as

```
 [ { "ID": "100", "name": "john" }, { "ID": "101", "name": "jim" }, { "ID": "102", "name": "jack" } ]
```

My robot code:

```
  should be equal    jack   ${Getjson[1]['name']}   msg=Name is not matching.   values=False
```

this code fails every time if the index changes in JSON.

How can I introduce for loop to check all index and match if it equals using robot framework or python?

Comment: what's the purpose of such test if you know the indices will change?

Comment: the JSON changes every time its index so I need to validate the values are matching

Comment: I dont understand which values do you expect to match and what "every time its index" means. And the code you are showing is not even a valid json.

Comment: I meant the value of the name is changing from 0th index to 1st index and back. So I have given [1] hardcoded manually but I am trying to use for loop and check all index.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko, oops! Sorry, I have pasted the wrong JSON now I have changed it can you pls guide on how can i use python code for checking all keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is filter `?(@.filtercondition)` in the JSONLibrary of robot framework that you can use. Note that it will always return list of value in case of multiple matching to the filter condition. and Jsonpath dont accept spaces and in conditions operand should be in single quotes.

```
${json}=      Convert String to JSON    ${Getjson}
${name}=      Get Value From Json         ${json}        $[?(@.name='john')].name 
# should be equal     john     ${name}[0]
List Should Contain Value   ${name}     john      // use this if you don't want to
...   rely on index. In case of empty list both keyword will assert to fail.
```

Also it will not guaranteed that it will match expected conditions if there are more than one matching nodes in the json for the given condition in the jsonpath

[image]

Comment: But why do you hardcode $[?(@.name='john')].name  john here ? I should just check whether the json keys has required values

Comment: It is same as adding [0] here, btw i dont understand that ${name}=      Get Value From Json         ${json}        $[?(@.name='john')].name  can you explain?
my requirement is I need to check JSON key name has a particular value or not?

Comment: I made it worked by $[?(@.name)].name  adding this

Comment: even you can go for `*` wild character

Comment: $[?(@.name)].name is this correct @Dev? can we use like this

Comment: yes its correct. I would have given that only. but in question the reference was for name value so added that filter

Comment: It is nothing but iterate every node of array where `name=='John'`, in the expression `?` is identifier of filter condition expression and `@` is to point current node of array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221117/discussion-between-mia-and-dev).

Comment: update with new json format with data how to use this filter here.
{'data': [{'ID': '100', 'name': 'jack'},{'ID': '101', 'name': 'jim'}]}
$[?(@.data)].name not working

Comment: use $.data[?(@.name)]